# problem with numbering when exporting to latex

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I am using LyX, and want to export into a LaTeX format. I did it, but when I compile, the number of citation or reference does not appear and a question mark appears instead. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: You have to invoke `bibtex` manually and `pdflatex` more than once. The required sequence for `paper.tex` is: `pdflatex paper; bibtex paper; pdflatex paper`. Depending on the packages you use, a third `pdflatex` run might be necessary.

Comment: With the information provided, I expect you need to run bibtex followed by running latex twice.

Comment: @Daniel, you comment answer perfectly the question. But as simple comment left the question as unanswered making a bit tedious the search for really unanswered questions.

Comment: @Fran: Thanks for the hint, I have made an answer from the comment.

Answer (score 2):

LyX does a great job in hiding the whistles and bells of tools that are required to generate the final PDF. Depending on the features and packages you use, this may include several runs of `pdflatex`, interwoven by invocations of `bibtex`, `makeidx`, etc; LyX reports this on the status bar while generating a PDF. When exporting to LaTeX and manually compiling the document, one has to do this by hand.

Unfortunately, LyX does not provide a log for exactly this type of information. However, in most cases (such as exporting a `paper.lyx` to `paper.tex` for submission) the following sequence is all you need:

```
pdflatex paper
bibtex paper
pdflatex paper
pdflatex paper
```

The third `pdflatex` run might not be necessary in many cases (depends on the packages you use), but also does not harm.